# Appending to a list comprehension in Python returns None

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

This is a question out of curiosity rather than trying to use it for a practical purpose.

Consider I have the following simple example where I generate a list through list comprehension:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [2 * i for i in a]
>>> b
[2, 4, 6]
>>> b.append(a)
>>> b
[2, 4, 6, [1, 2, 3]]
```

However if I try and do this all in one action

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [2 * i for i in a].append(a)
>>> b == None
True
```

The result returns `None`. Is there any reason why this is the case?

I would have thought that an action like this would either return an answer like in the first example or throw an error.

For reference I'm using Python 3.6.5

Comment: This has nothing to do with list comprehensions, but with `.append()`. `[1, 2, 3].append(4)` also returns `None`

Comment: Interesting, never thought to try it on a list by itself

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`append` only works on variables, not list literals, since it updates the list object itself and does not return the resulting list.

As @Tomalak mentioned noted, running a similar operation on a simple list also returns  `None`

```
>>> [1, 2, 3].append(4) == None
True
```

Comment: And as we all know, when a Python function doesn't return anything it implicitly returns `None`.

Comment: If you can add in some of the content from Tomalak's comment on my question, I'll mark this as correct.

Comment: @ScottMcC Done as suggested. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can use concatination `+` instead of `append` in list comprehension

```
In [1]: a = [1, 2, 3]

In [2]: b = [2 * i for i in a] + [a]

In [3]: b
Out[3]: [2, 4, 6, [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: the trick here is make the new element a list by adding `[` and `]` .  I disagree with python not doing that for us.  I end up having to re-figure this out from time to time

Answer (score 1):

**@ScottMcC**, methods defined on mutable objects like **list**, **dictionary** mostly perform operations on calling object and doesn't return anything.

In case of immutable object like **string** you may see, methods return the modified form(a different object) of the calling object. In case of **list**, it's different.

> You can't expect the below operations on **list** kind of mutable objects.

```
s = "hello DJANGO"
s2 = s.upper() 
s3 = s.lower() 

print(s)  # hello DJANGO
print(s2) # HELLO DJANGO
print(s3) # hello django
```

Now, have a look at the below examples.

> **list** is mutable object.
>
> Calling **sort()** method on list directly modified the calling object and doesn't return anything (That's why **None**).
>
> Calling **sorted()** function doesn't alter the passing list. It creates a separate sorted list based on the passed list. As it is not a method defined on list object, it returns the new sorted list.
>
> **append()** method appends item on the calling list and doesn't return anything. Once you call it, you are done with updating (appending an item) the list.

```
# sort() method defined on list updates the calling list
# As it updates current list, it doesn't return anything. That's why None.
a = [5, 8, 1, 2, 7]
n = a.sort()
print (a)
print(n)
print ()

# sorted() function returns a new sorted list 
# It doesn't update the calling list a2 
a2 = [5, 8, 1, 2, 7];
n = sorted(a2);
print (a2)
print(n)
print()

# append() is method defined on list, it updates calling list so it doesn't return anything (None)
l = []
n = l.append(34)
print(l)
print (n)
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2, 5, 7, 8]
None

[5, 8, 1, 2, 7]
[1, 2, 5, 7, 8]

[34]
None
```